# Move Oracle11gXE 32bit DB to Oracle11gXE 64 bit version

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-backups, database-restore

Firstly, I am not a DB Administrator. I had an issue wtih APEX installed in my Oracle11gXE 32 bit version. So, taking this as opportunity, I uninstalled this (took a backup of oraclexe folder) and installed Oracle 11gXE 64 bit version.

Now I need to restore or move the database to 64bit version.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: When you say "took a back-up" what did you actually do?  Literally a copy of the entire folder?

Comment: I took a copy of oraclexe folder & I also ran backup command and have a full set backup in fast_recovery_area folder.